# Use minSdkVersion 7

Tags: java, android-studio, google-admin-sdk

I need in my app this piece of code:

```
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
```

But I also need the minSdkVersion to be 7, and tha doesn't work.
The error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71
```

This is the content of my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "codificador.aplicacion.safrapp.codificadorandroid"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
}
```

Isn't there an smaller version of compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services?, 
because this is what causes my error.

UPDATE:
I changed it to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'`
New error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89
```

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'

Comment: I tried that, another error appeared: Check the Update.

Comment: whats your manifest ?

Comment: `I also need the minSdkVersion to be 7` API Level 7 is out of the market, nowadays: less than the 0.1% of the global market. https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Finally understand your problem . **`Google Play Services`** is supported on `Android 2.3.3` and above.Set this :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71' // or 6.1.+
```

or

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

And set   `minSdkVersion 15` . I hope it helps you a lot

Comment: But I need my minSdkVersion to be 7